# Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [String]’ with actual type ‘[String]’

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I have these two code snippets, which I'd guess do the same thing, but they don't. Why is that?

This one works fine:

```
fdup :: String -> IO ()
fdup filename = do
        h <- openFile filename ReadMode
        c <- hGetContents h
        putStr $ unlines $ parse $ lines c
        hClose h
```

This one returns an error `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [String]’ with actual type ‘[String]’`:

```
fdup' :: String -> IO ()
fdup' filename = do
        h <- openFile filename ReadMode
        c <- hGetContents h
        ls <- lines c
        putStr $ unlines $ parse $ ls
        hClose h
```

`parse :: [String] -> [String]`

What is the difference between them?

Comment: The error is probaby located in `ls <- lines c`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't get it why...

Comment: because if you write `x <- some_expr`, then `some_expr` needs to be of type `Monad m => m a`, and then `x` is of type `a`. Throughout a `do` block one uses the same monad `m`. `do` notation unfortunately may suggest that is just a bit of a different "style". But in fact here monads come in to play. In short the idea is that Haskell is a *pure* functional language, and that a call with the same parameter always gives the same result. Stateful actions, like opening a file, etc. thus require a state. A monad *can* be used to *implictly* pass that state.

Comment: Now it's clear to me, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: `ls <- return $ lines c` wold work.

Comment: @WillNess Why involve `<-` or `return` at all? Why not just `let ls = lines c`?

Comment: @JosephSible for uniformity? also, I was illustrating to the OP the types mismatch in their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem explained, you don't need `<-` in that specific place because `lines c` is just a list of strings, and not an `IO` computation. If you want to give it a name, you can use a let-binding instead:

```
fdup' :: String -> IO ()
fdup' filename = do
        h <- openFile filename ReadMode
        c <- hGetContents h
        let ls = lines c
        putStr $ unlines $ parse $ ls
        hClose h
```